# Spring restTemplate not returning anything

Tags: spring-mvc

```
    @Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}

@GetMapping("/printJson")
public String getJson(@RequestParam(name="reports", required=false, defaultValue="None") RestTemplate restTemplate, Model model) throws Exception {
    List<DailyReport> reports = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/pwa/services/dailyReport/all", 
            (Class<List<DailyReport>>) ((Class)List.class));
    model.addAttribute("reports", reports);
    return "printJson";
}
```

Hi, I am trying to consume my own webservice with restTemplate. On my webservice I have stored data with JSON and I want to print it or use it with a web application

This is what my json file looks like :

```
{
    "serial_number": 202102,
    "report_date":"2019-11-23T23:00:00.000+0000",
    "status": "en service",

    "automate_information":{
        "state": "ok",
        "temperature": 20,

        "payment_state":{
            "coins": "normal",
            "smart_card": "normal",
            "card": "normal"
        }
    },

  "errors":[
    {"type": "ax23", "description": "azerty"},
    {"type": "cx400", "description": "qzerty"}
  ],

    "articles":[
        {"name": "cafe", "quantity": 20},
        {"name": "chocolat", "quantity": 30},
        {"name": "oasis", "quantity": 10}
    ],

    "income": 300
}
```

I have made a matching structure with the same names and all, but when I launch my application and I go on the corresponding view :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>JSON</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <tr th:each="report: ${reports}">
        <td th:text="${report.id}" />
        <td th:text="${report.serial_number}" />
    </tr>

    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing at all is printed. When I tried to call the .size() on the variable reports, I had the error : Cannot call .size() function on null.

I have searched everywhere, and looked back at my structure to see if the names were exactly alike and didn't find anything.
Is there something wrong I am doing with resttemplate ?

Thank you a lot for your help, I might have done a lot of mistakes I am new to spring.

Comment: What happens when you hit this URL from a web browser ?

Comment: It shows data stored in a json format.

I solved my issue, it was something I didn't know about spring. I didn't put my class that launchs everything on top of every packages I need. My servlet was just out of context.

I don't know how to close the subject though ^^